# One color bar for 1 row subplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a subplot 1x5. The first column is gray image range 0-255 and the second column shows the label image range from 0 to 2. The three remaining images show output results ranges from -3 to 10, and the type is float. I want to use 1 color bar for the last three images. I tried below method but the results are not expected.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(151)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(152)
plt.imshow(label, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(153)
plt.imshow(output1, vmin=-3, vmax=10)
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(154)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(output2, vmin=-3, vmax=10)

plt.subplot(155)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(output3, vmin=-3, vmax=10)


plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Get the handles for the last three axes and the last Imshow and pass them as a list: plt.colorbar(pcm, ax=[ax3, ax4, ax5])

Comment: great solution. Could you please write it by code?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-colorbar-placement-py

Comment: I need a solution code than the reference. I read it before